# Flutter | 3. To keep 1 item in the row

Tags: flutter, gridview, grid

For example, when using GridView in Flutter I only want one item to stay at index 3.
The other item on the right (shown in the picture) should go one down.I left a picture below. You will understand what I mean.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGPm0.png)

```
GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                  ),
                  itemCount: BesiktasSaha.dataName.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (deneme1 == true) {
                                  sayi1 = index;
                                  deneme1 = false;
                                  isigiYak = false;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.5),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image:
                                        AssetImage(dataData[index].playerImg),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                height: 150,
                                width: 150,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '${dataData[index].name}',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: A quick solution would be to create a list of all the widgets first and build the grid with that list. Now when user clicks on an item, just insert an empty container (same size as your list items) onto the list on that position and rebuild. Keep track of the index, when another click is detected, remove the previous container first and then insert a new one at the new position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form `BesiktasSaha.dataName` to new List, and insert a empty item in every 3 item.

There is an example in `DartPad` :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String?> items = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]; /// Your original list
    List<String?> newItems = []; /// Your new list
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0) {
        newItems.add(null); /// insert a null item
      }
      newItems.add(items[i]);
    }
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemCount: newItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return (newItems[index] == null)
              ? Container() /// if the item is null, display empty
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text(
                    newItems[index]!,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ));
        });
  }
}
```

[image: The Grid will look like]

Comment: Oh, really ? So good. And worked! <3

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it correct so that other people who might have the same problem can see it